# Cannot read property 'version' of null

Tags: npm, powerbi, npm-start, pbiviz

I'm fairly new to Power BI. I want to replace the existing visual controls with my custom controls (Date slicer of its own with my custom Calendar). I created a new project as suggested by [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/custom-visual-develop-tutorial) tutorial. When I did so, it throws error.

As many article said, the first error was a warning and can be ignored.But it doesn't seem so.However I ignored.But I can't get rid of the second issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Hope I get some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I am having the same issue. I have seen that the version of might be an issue; I am on Node 8.9.3. Have seen some thread where you need to upgrade Node to v12.

Comment: I too have the same version as you mentioned. Issue resolved after upgrading node.

Comment: Thanks for the resolution. I may actually move to creating a visual using Python instead of modifying a JS visual.

Comment: You can also create visual using JS. All you need is to do is upgrade node.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command in your terminal for your first warning,

```
1.$ npm cache clean --force
2.delete node_modules by $ rm -rf node_modules
3.$ npm install
And then start it again with $ npm start
```

Comment: I tried it out. When I run the project, it throws the same.

Comment: No more changes. Same issue persists.